# Can't assign value of type 'T' to instance of type 'T'

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core

I'm writing code that avoids the overhead of `Convert.ChangeType()`. But I'm getting hung up one one little detail, which is illustrated below.

```
public void GetValue(out T value)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        value = (T)""; // <== Cannot convert 'string' to 'T' 

    // ...

}
```

I have a value that I know is of type `T`, but how can I assign that value to an instance of type `T` with minimal overhead? I'm really hoping for something fast and simple. Otherwise, I'll scrap my code and use `Convert.ChangeType()` in a `try...catch` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it to `object` first:

```
value = (T)(object)"";
```

Even though you've done a check for type compatibility the compiler doesn't look at this. As far as it's concerned you've got a `T` and a `string` which there isn't a direct cast. You have to bounce the string down to an `object` first (for which there is a direct cast) and then cast to `T` which as far as the compiler is concerned may fail, but won't because you've already checked the type!

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if that *bouncing down to an `object`* adds much overhead?

Comment: It's a runtime check, the same as any other downcast. I wouldn't worry too much about it!

Comment: It's compile-time information. Casting to `object` merely removes the compiler's static type infomation about the string value so it can't balk at casting a string to `T`.

Comment: @Sean boxing (which is quite possible as OP did not show they restrictions on T) could really easy lead to significant perf cost...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - His `if` statement has checked that `T` is a `string` so casting it to an `object` won't require boxing.

Comment: @Sean indeed. It is always my problem - I see what people posted as *example* of what they want not an *exact and only* thing... (Both comments will "self-destruct" in a day or so)